# Invalid ViewState error after conversion from ASP.NET 1.1 to ASP.Net 3.5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

***[I'm posting our problem and solution below as an FYI. If you have an official statement from Microsoft or a representative organization about this issue, I'll mark that as an answer. Otherwise, my post below will serve as the answer].***

#### The Problem:

We took a ASP.NET 1.1 app and converted it to ASP.Net 3.5. When we double-clicked on an item on a page, or selected the item and clicked the OK button - both of which fire the same post-back function - page processing halted on the server with an Invalid ViewState error.

**What we did to debug:** This is for a program which resides on a company intranet. Due to it being .Net 1.1, the program is heavily targeted towards Internet Explorer - the JavaScript doesn't run on other browsers. F12 developer tools brings up the JavaScript debugging console in Internet Explorer. Attaching to the IIS 7.5 process (w3wp.exe) with Visual Studio allowed us to view C# server code errors.

**What we found:**  There is a hidden field on the web page called __EventValidation. Based on examining the C# errors on the server with Visual Studio, we saw that ASP.Net is taking the value of that field and interpreting it as the value of the ViewState field (ViewState is an encoded string containing information about the page), which is in another hidden field (We could see both values in the page using F12 developer tools). BUT -  these pages have no ViewState value - it is specifically disabled in the code with "EnableViewState = false".

The structure of this page is a containing .aspx page with no other data than an iframe containing a child url which displays the page with data.

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed as it stands. Pose it as a question, remove the solution section, and then add and accept that as an answer. Perhaps put you pre-amble in the answer too.

Comment: @JonP, thanks for the heads up. I edited my other similarly structured question and posted our solution as the answer.  I think it can help readers as this was quite an abstruse bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[I'm posting our problem and solution in this initial post as an FYI. If you have an official statement from Microsoft or a representative organization about this issue, I'll mark that as an answer. Otherwise, this post will serve as the answer].**

#### The solution:

I set a flag in the web.config file called enableEventValidation to false, as follows:

```
<pages enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Auto">
```

This flag is not available in the 1.x framework. Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.enableeventvalidation(v=vs.90).aspx

I originally thought this was opening up a security hole, but it is simply restoring .Net 1.1 behavior. From the link above: "The EnableEventValidation attribute indicates whether event validation should be performed. The default value is true. A Web application can optionally disable event validation to revert to .NET Framework version 1.0 behavior."

This restored original functionality.

This was similar to the Invalid ViewState MAC error widely reported. But it was a different error. I originally found the solution for the web.config update here:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/03/14/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error.aspx - but instead of setting viewStateEncryptionMode="Never", we set it to "Auto" and it still works.